# Error when trying to set checkedtextview from SQLite DB

Tags: java, android, checkedtextview

I'm trying to get my checkedTextView state from my SQLite database but it is crashing the app.

Here is the code implemented:

```java
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM list", null);
 int foundIndex = c.getColumnIndex("found");
 while (c != null) {
      c.getString(foundIndex);
      c.moveToNext();
 }
 String[] foundList = new String[foundIndex];
 arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 for (String found : levelOneListList){
      if (levelOneListList == foundList){
          levelOneListView.setItemChecked(found.indexOf(foundIndex), true);
      }
 }
}
```

And it is giving this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.woodlandwanderer/com.example.woodlandwanderer.levelOneActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: your foundIndex is the reason for crash. you checked that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, your cursor size is 0 and you are trying to access first.

add the following check before your loop.

`if (c.moveToNext() && c.getCount()>0) {`

Comment: Doesn't seem to have changed anything, it's still throwing up the same error.

Comment: What is the size of the cursor and value of the foundIndex?

Comment: Ah! I understand the problem! The cursor size will be 0 the first time it loads as it will be populated as list items are checked. Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: I was being stupid, put the if statement in the wrong place. Will try again with it in the right place

Comment: Although I am getting an error now when the app is restarted, suggesting that there is an issue when retrieving the data

Answer (score 0):

Read your cursor data like this. Looks like your cursor size is 0.

```
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        do {

           int foundIndex = c.getColumnIndex("found");
           c.getString(foundIndex);

        } while (c.moveToNext());

      c.close(); // close your db cursor
    }

// list update and set checkbox value here
```